# Can I setup blog subscriptions on SharePoint 2007?

Tags: alert, blog

Currently the best way I can think to do this is to have anybody who'd like to "subscribe" to a blog use the alerts feature. However, is there a way to setup actual subscriptions?

If the alert feature is what needs to be used, is it possible for people to see who is currently setup to be alerted for their blog posts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users have to login to read your blog, you could let them use alerts for that. If they don't have to login, you need to write some custom code:
* collect personal details, store them in a list or database.
* event receiver on the bloglist that sends mail to all persons in that list.

take care of:
* sending bulkmail: you could get blacklisted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use RSS for that.  You can create several views on the Posts list, filtered by users and present a subscription page to the users where they could subscribe to the full blog feed, or subscribe to a particular view.